# Spark load parquet can't infer timestamp from partitioned column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I can save a parquet file partitioned by a column that looks like a timestamp, but is actually a string. When I try to load that parquet back into spark using `spark.read.load()`, it automatically infers the partitioned column has a date, causing me to lose all my time information. Is there a way to read the parquet file back in with the partitioned column as a string or better yet have it automatically parse into a timestamp given a specified format? Here's an example:

```
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('2020-01-01T00-00-01', 'hello'),
    ],
    [
        'test_dt', 'col1'
    ]
)
test_df.write.save('hdfs:///user/test_write', 'parquet', mode='overwrite', partitionBy='test_dt')
test_read = spark.read.load('hdfs:///user/test_write', 'parquet')
test_read.show(1)
```

This returns:

```
+-----+----------+
| col1|   test_dt|
+-----+----------+
|hello|2020-01-01|
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: That's expected. Partitioned data doesn't preserve type information (it is just directory structure). You'll have to cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` to `false` before read, Spark will seize all attempts to infer data types of partition columns (they will be treated as strings).